# Highcharts / Highstock Invalid Date Issue

Tags: java, javascript, highcharts, timestamp

I get an invalid date error when I try to use Highstock the graph gets drawn but I can not hover over points see code listing below. The Timestamps are generated by Java using System.currentTimeMillis().
Could someone please tell me are those Timestamps not supported by Highcharts???

```
 $(function() {

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Headline'
        },

        series : [{
            "name":"testname",
            "data":[
                [1384961978275,1700],
                [1384875578275,1600],
                [1384789178275,1750],
                [1384702778275,1500],
                [1384616378275,1900],
                [1384529978275,1870]
                    ]
                }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you should start by specifying type: 'datetime' for one of your axis (x or y)

Comment: First, sort your data ascending (required for Highstock). You don't need to specify that type, since Highstock has only datetime xAxis.

Comment: Sweet it was the ordering thank you.

Comment: @PawełFus you are genius man (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with unsorted data. Data for Highstock should be sorted ascending (by x-values/timestamps) because of dataGrouping feature.